# chmod 755 for directories - does this allow everyone to delete the folder?

Tags: unix, permissions, chmod

Does the "execute" bit also mean "deletion" permissions, or do I need "write" permissions for that?

Answer (score 2):

To remove a directory, the parent of that directory must be writable by the effective user. The `write` and `execute` flags of the directory being removed do not matter.

Additionally, one cannot remove a directory if it is not empty. Often a user will use the `rm -r` command to remove a non-empty directory tree recursively by first removing all its contents. If the user does not have write permission to the subdirectories, he/she cannot empty their contents first.

Comment: So, what if the directory is created by PHP. If the user has write permissions to the parent server, he can still delete this subfolder?

Comment: @Wesley Assuming you mean **directory** not **server**, then yes. If the user has write permissions to the parent directory, they can remove the subdirectory. You might want to rephrase your question to ask what you are really concerned about. A better solution might exist.

Comment: I'm not sure where I said server? I meant when I create a directory in PHP (so server side) via the mkdir() function. I also create subfolders in that folder, so /parent/child/grandchild -- only parent is created by the user, the rest by php. Will the user be able to remove via FTP if chmod is 755? (assuming php runs as nobody)

Comment: @Wesley How are you adding subdirectories to a parent directory owned by the user if PHP is running as nobody? Unless PHP is running as a group that has write permissions to the parent directory, mkdir() should fail.

Comment: The user has set the necessary permissions on the parent folder (temporarily).

Comment: @Wesley One cannot remove a directory if it is non-empty. Often a user will use the `rm -r` command to remove a non-empty directory tree recursively by first removing all its contents. If the user does not have write permissions to the child or grandchild directories, they cannot empty their contents first.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4274/discussion-between-kurt-s-and-wesley)

Answer (score 1):

No, the 'execute' bit is used by directories to determine whether a 'user' can view the files listed in the directory. In regards to deletion the relevant bit is the 'write' permission bit of the **parent** directory.

Comment: So, what if the directory is created by PHP. Does the parent server still control deletion?